# Why does the converted image seem laggy when it is moving?

Tags: python, pygame

I was trying to create a simple pygame game that uses sprites, but when i compiled the code the movement seemed to have some kind of lag spikes. I did some debugging and extracted the problem into the code below. The image moves smoothly for most of a second, but then a lag spike occurs and so on.
I've seen that converting images helped a lot of people, but nothing changed for me.

```
import pygame, sys

class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Spaceshooter")
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("player.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            self.screen.fill("black")
            self.rect.x += 5
            self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
            self.clock.tick(60)
            pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = Game()
    game.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reduce the movement speed and increase the fps. I believe it will help you, Adam.